# Should I let my cultists eat poop?

Tags: cult-of-the-lamb

One of my cultists really wants to try and eat some poop. Is this a good idea? It doesn’t sound like a good idea.

What will happen if I let them eat a little poop sometimes, as a treat?

Comment: Until I noticed the tag, this sounded like one hell of a bizarre question!

Comment: Btw, real life cultists [should probably not](https://www.healthline.com/health/what-happens-if-you-eat-poop) [eat poop](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/what-happens-if-you-eat-poop) :x

Comment: [Somewhat Related](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsVgi8hoFFc&ab_channel=RobotElf)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally it's not recommended to feed your cultists poop, as it only reduces the hunger slightly but has a 50% chance of causing illness and diarrhea:
[image: Bowl of poop]

There is a side quest, though. That is probably the cultist you are refering to. At one point a cultist really wants to try some poop, and when you feed it to him, **it increases his loyalty** towards you. In this single case, I would recommend feeding your cultist poop.